# Start Virtual Machines with Virtualbox Using File Path

Tags: shell, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a virtual machine I run with virtual box on Linux Debian.
It is placed within a hidden Truecrypt container.

I like to curtail the existence of that VM as best as possible.
Therefore importing the VM to virtual box leaving an entry in its GUI
is not what I want. (I could every time manually remove it, but this is laborious
and in case of emergency shut-down not possible.)

Is there any way to start a virtual machine with virtualbox, by
using the path to a .vbox file instead of importing a file and then using the name of the imported VM?

So instead of:

```
vboxmanage startvm <Name_Of_VM_Here>
```

Something like:

```
vboxmanage startvm <Path_to_VMDK_file>
```

Comment: Could those who down voted me at the very least explain why? I can not see anything wrong with my question. Indeed I regard it as totally valid and rightfully asked. Someone else even added it to her favorites.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
vboxmanage showhdinfo "PathToYourVMDK"
```

which will show you its UUID in the last line of output.

Then you can start that VM using the UUID instead of its name with

```
vboxmanage startvm YourUUID
```

So, essentially the command you would need is:

```
vboxmanage startvm $(vboxmanage showhdinfo "PathToYourVMDK" | awk -F" |)" '/^In use/{print $(NF-1)}')
```

If you are not using `bash`, you will need to replace the `$()` by backticks like this:

```
vboxmanage startvm `vboxmanage showhdinfo "PathToYourVMDK" | awk -F" |)" '/^In use/{print $(NF-1)}'`
```

**Updated**

If you are having trouble scripting this and debugging the script, follow these steps.

Firstly... get the basic `showhdinfo` command working. So try this:

```
vboxmanage showhdinfo "PathToYourVMDK"

UUID:           c3166b8a-3c21-4531-927c-030f3cfb9728
Parent UUID:    base
State:          created
Type:           normal (base)
Location:       ...
Storage format: VDI
Format variant: fixed default
Capacity:       8192 MBytes
Size on disk:   8192 MBytes
In use by VMs:  UbuntuVM (UUID: 77743eca-e338-471c-b824-60c5c5c22b6f)   <-- THIS ONE
```

Secondly... now look at the last line, that UUID can be used with `vboxmanage startvm`, so try copying that and pasting it like this:

```
vboxmanage startvm 77743eca-e338-471c-b824-60c5c5c22b6f
```

That should start the VM.

Thirdly... next check is thaet the `awk` is extracting that UUID correctly, so let's try that

```
vboxmanage showhdinfo "PathToYourVMDK" | awk -F" |)" '/^In use/{print $(NF-1)}'

77743eca-e338-471c-b824-60c5c5c22b6f
```

That looks correct, now put it all into a script:

```
#!/bin/bash -xv
UUID=$(vboxmanage showhdinfo "PathToYourVMDK" | awk -F" |)" '/^In use/{print $(NF-1)}')
echo UUID:$UUID
vboxmanage startvm $UUID
```

Comment: Thanks, Mark! I will test it out and then decide whether I accept your answer.

Comment: It does not work for me. I put the command into a shell script with a relative path to the VMDK. The shell the tutors me about the correct usage of the vbox command (like arguments --type gui|sdl|headless). How could I make it work?

Comment: Make the first line of your script `#!/bin/bash -xv` and run it again. Edit your question and paste in the output.

Comment: I have added some extra information to help you debug it - please let me know how it goes.